# Gradle - Build Error

Tags: netflix-eureka

I am new to Netflix eureka and Gradle, I am trying to build eureka client and server which is a gradle project; I checked out the code from "github.com/Netflix/eureka" and tried to build using "./gradlew clean build", but it is failing, below is the error message -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'eureka'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.netflix.nebula:nebula-bintray-plugin:2.2.0.
>    Required by:
>        :eureka:unspecified > com.netflix.nebula:gradle-netflixoss-project-plugin:2.2.7
>   Could not HEAD 'http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/netflix/nebula/nebula-bintray-plugin/2.2.0/nebula-bintray-plugin-2.2.0.pom'.
>   peer not authenticated
>
> ### ..........
>
> Things I tried 
>   1> I added Proxy details in gradlew
>   DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=some.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=xyz -Dhttps.proxyPassword=123 -Dhttp.proxyHost=some.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=xyz -Dhttp.proxyPassword=123"

2> Downloaded certificate from plugins.gradle.org and added to java keystore; I added the certificate in the following way
  2a. Launched firefox and went to plugins.gradle.org
  2b. Viewed PEM file and saved it as pluginsgradleorg.cer (selecting All Files)
  2c. Added it to Java Keystore @ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/security using 
      "keytool -import -alias gradleplungin -file pluginsgradleorg.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit"
  2d. After "Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes" it showed "Certificate was added to keystore".

After these two fix also the error remains.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, java version "1.7.0_65"

Any help in this regard is welcome and thanks in advance.
Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: No, I could not.. I used Spring Cloud Eureka.