# unable to build netflix-eureka gradle project

Tags: gradle, gradlew, netflix-eureka

I am facing the **exact** same issue as this person, with the exact same steps taken to resolve it to no avail. There were no answers/comments on his question so i'm posting again to see if anyone has any idea.

Adding the certificates did not seem to make a difference. Still fails with same error. Anyone know what it could be?

Original (unanswered) question: [Gradle - Build Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507722/gradle-build-error)

Thanks!

The result of executing **./gradlew clean build** is:

igor.trivunic@comp /c/direc/eureka (master)

$ ./gradlew clean build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\direc\eureka\build.gradle' line: 10
- What went wrong:
  Error resolving plugin [id: 'nebula.netflixoss', version: '2.2.10']

  > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.2.1/plugin/use/nebula.netflixoss/2.2.10'.
  >   peer not authenticated
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.725 secs

Comment: Where's the repo of the project you're trying to build?

Comment: Sorry for not including this. It is here: git clone https://github.com/Netflix/eureka.git

Comment: It works correctly on my workstation. Are you using gradlew? Are you behind proxy?

Comment: I am executing the exact same command as suggested in the documentation "./gradlew clean build"

I've updated the question with the error it comes back with.

I am **not** behind a proxy.

Comment: I've just did exactly the same and it finishes with *BUILD SUCCESSFUL* every time. Just can't reproduce it.

Comment: your environment is obviously set up correctly from previous similar work. Thanks for the help. I have tried this on a different machine, and this time I was shown JNA errors instead of authentication errors.